# expect script terminating early in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, expect

I've got an `expect` script that I need to run in a Dockerfile.  However, the script is terminating after all of the input is sent.  What's interesting is that `docker build` is succeeding.  Here's my MRE:

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt -y update && \
    apt -y install expect

COPY script.sh expect.exp /root/
RUN cd /root && \
    ./expect.exp
```

expect.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ./script.sh
expect {
    "Foo? " {
        send "Y\n"
    }
}

interact
```

script.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash -e

echo "Foo? "
read var
echo "Creating watermark"
touch watermark
```

I'm building with

```bash
docker build --progress=plain -t blah .
```

I see

```
...
#8 [4/4] RUN cd /root && ./expect.exp
#8 0.244 spawn ./script.sh
#8 0.245 + echo 'Foo? '
#8 0.245 Foo?
#8 0.245 + read var
#8 DONE 0.3s
```

`/root/watermark` never gets created.  However, if I run a container based on the image and execute `./expect.exp`, it works as expected.

Comment: You might want to use `yes Y | ./script.sh` instead of using expect

Comment: However the problem seems to be that `read var` is returning non-zero and the bash `-e` option is killing the shell script.

Comment: @glennjackman, while `yes` works in this particular scenario, why wouldn't `expect` work?

Comment: Try `#!/usr/bin/expect -df` to turn on expect's verbose debugging to see what's happening. Normally one "hits enter" with `\r`, but `\n` should work.

Comment: Ah, adding `\r` did it.

Comment: @glennjackman, Want to post that as the answer?

Comment: No, I don't have a good explanation for it. You are welcome to answer your own question with the fix that worked for you.